# Android. Find child by Id in custom Toolbar

Tags: android

I have Toolbar layout with child:

```
<md.fusionworks.paynet.ui.widget.PaynetToolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay">

    <md.fusionworks.paynet.ui.widget.FontTextView
        android:id="@+id/titleField"
        style="@style/ModuleTitleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        view:font="font/Circe-Light.otf" />

</md.fusionworks.paynet.ui.widget.PaynetToolbar>
```

And extended Toolbar class:

```
public class PaynetToolbar extends Toolbar {

    @Bind(R.id.titleField)
    TextView titleField;

    public PaynetToolbar(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        titleField.setText("test");
    }
}
```

My goal is to create an extended toolbar with child items and this extended toolbar will find children.

But i don't know how to correct create extended toolbar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I need to address your idea of finding children of Android widgets:

> This is not a good idea, because the resource id names can change any time with new SDK or library updates, without any warning. This means your code might just stop working.

---

Still, if you *need* to do it, there are some solutions.
You can use Android Device Monitor to look up the hierarchy of inflated view of your app. It will show you the resource id (if there is any) you could then hardcode to find it with findViewById. The ADM hierarchy dump looks something like this:

[image]

Sometimes a child might not have an id, then you can find it with reflection or iterate through Toolbar children and check the type:

```java
int count = toolbar.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    View v = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof TextView) {
       // you found a TextView, you can do something to it
   }
}
```

Probably the solution will be a combination of every trick described above, but still - it's risky to hardcode the structure and resource ids.

Comment: Hmm.. this mean that in my case extended toolbar is bad idea )) Thanks

Comment: well, it depends. If you want to look up only views you created in your extended Toolbar, it's perfectly good idea. If you want to access original Toolbar views, you need to decide how far and how much you really need to reach. If my answer helped you, please mark it as answered ;) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are already extending Toolbar, and by default, Toolbar which is a View has the method findViewById. With your constructor in your custom toolbar passing context and attrs on super, it is all set. So, you can call it from your custom Toolbar.

You need to check if the FontTextView which is also an custom view if it has the constructor passing context and attrs on super.

```
public FontTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

In your activity or fragment you can do:

```
PaynetToolbar myToolbar = (PaynetToolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
titleField = (FontTextView) myToolbar.findViewById(R.id.titleField);
```

Comment: Thanks. But  i need to find childs inside extended toolbar not in activity/fragment :)))

Comment: In this case I think you need to inflate a FontTextView inside your PaynetToolbar in order to use it.